# Javascript: addEventListener with onkeydown doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript

If you replace "onkeydown" with "click", it reacts, at least.

```
<input id="yourinput" type="text" />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("yourinput").addEventListener("onkeydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField() {
alert("functional");    
if(keycode==13) {
        alert("You hit the enter key.");
    }
    else{
        alert("Oh no you didn't.");
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The event type should be  `"keydown"`, notice that you don't need the *on* prefix:

```
element.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);
```

Note also that you should get the `keyCode` from the event object in your handler:

```
function keyDownTextField (e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  //...
}
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/uteha3/3).